Angular custom elements keeps giving NullInjectorError
I really think I am really close, but I can't seem to get it to work. Probably something stupid.
What I try to do:
A client has a WordPress website and I want to embed a piece of Angular inside the WordPress website. How I do is not really important, but I want to let you know the ultimate goal of this weeks adventure.
I know the host supports NodeJS as I can run a complete Angular TS app in a subdomain.
I have followed many tutorials and I always end with the same: Some lame error that doesn't make much sense (like most errors).
To make sure it can what I want I created a very simple Angular application with a component called "my-embedded", as stand alone component. The parts, base dir is src/app:
my-embedded/my-embedded.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-embedded-element',
    standalone: true,  
    template: `<h1>Hello from Angular Standalone Element!</h1>`,
})
export class MyEmbeddedComponent {}

I don't need the HTML and CSS for now, so I removed those.
app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    template: ''
})
export class AppComponent {
  
}

Should do nothing, so it's empty. HTML, SCSS, and test are removed.
Thanks to some other post on SO I changed my main.ts:
import 'zone.js'; // Required for Angular
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements'; // Polyfill for custom elements if necessary
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyEmbeddedComponent } from './app/my-embedded/my-embedded.component';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';

// Bootstrap the standalone component as a custom element
bootstrapApplication(MyEmbeddedComponent).then((ref) => {
    const injector = ref.injector;
    const myElement = createCustomElement(MyEmbeddedComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('my-embedded-element', myElement);
});

I build the whole project with
ng build --configuration=production --optimization=false
This makes the JS files larger than 1MB, so I had to change the budgets of the production in the angular.json:
"budgets": [
    {
        "type": "initial",
        "maximumWarning": "2mb",
        "maximumError": "2mb"
    }

This is the complete angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-elements-project": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-elements-project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "angular-elements-project:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "angular-elements-project:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "angular-elements-project:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I could use the g build --configuration=production --output-hashing=none, but then it won't give me correct errors. I will use this one when it works.
This gives me a bunch of files. I copy all the JS files to a local webserver and add an index.html with the following HTML:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-critters-container>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularElementsProject</title>
    <base href="/CrawlerWebsite/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <my-embedded-element></my-embedded-element>

    <script src="polyfills-TGKJVAXZ.js"></script>
    <script src="main-G5IVIT5U.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

When I open the index.html on the service I get this error:
polyfills-TGKJVAXZ.js:1828 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[_ComponentFactoryResolver$12 -> _ComponentFactoryResolver$12]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for _ComponentFactoryResolver$12!
        at NullInjector.get (main-G5IVIT5U.js:5058:21)
        at R3Injector.get (main-G5IVIT5U.js:5940:27)
        at R3Injector.get (main-G5IVIT5U.js:5940:27)
        at getComponentInputs (main-G5IVIT5U.js:50206:45)
        at createCustomElement (main-G5IVIT5U.js:50444:18)
        at main-G5IVIT5U.js:50518:21
        at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (polyfills-TGKJVAXZ.js:300:158)
        at _ZoneImpl.run (polyfills-TGKJVAXZ.js:94:35)
        at polyfills-TGKJVAXZ.js:2004:30
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills-TGKJVAXZ.js:326:171)

It does work and I do see the text from the custom element, but this console error keep bothering me.
Some websites/solutions say that I should change
bootstrapApplication(MyEmbeddedComponent).then((ref) => {
    const injector = ref.injector;
    const myElement = createCustomElement(MyEmbeddedComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('my-embedded-element', myElement);
});

to
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent).then((ref) => {
    const injector = ref.injector;
    const myElement = createCustomElement(MyEmbeddedComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('my-embedded-element', myElement);
});

But when I do that, the error says it can't find app-root.
Other solutions on Google, SO, ChatGPT don't do much and it keeps giving me the same error.

did you update your index.html after you updated the main.ts? index.html should have the app-root. please check and let me know

@cfprabhu do you mean in the index.html of the website where I want to embed the Angular element? No, it's set to the my-embedded-element, as shown in the code of my post. Or do I need to add it somewhere else?

please check this https://medium.com/@ashishmr272/create-custom-web-elements-using-angular-16-integrate-with-html-3d21e81c223c

@cfprabhu Okay, I did everything (until the input properties). My screen is blank and I get the same error. Is there something wrong with my Angular?

I have done something similar, however instead I had a separate function which did the bundling , then I added it to the index.html file. However you can try adding it to an iframe which I did in my case something like this

Lastly the path was hosted to an s3 bucket
@AmenawonEsezobor Thank you for your reply. Maybe it's good to know I am a back-end developer with some knowledge of Angular(TS). Enough to create whole apps, but sometimes it's somewhat magic to me. I know the iframe-trick, but I find it harder to style inside a non-Angular app. Hence the idea of the embedded piece of Angular. The element also needs to receive info from the WordPress website. I think an IFrame will be harder to control.

As Angular docs states:

Avoid using the component's selector as the custom element tag name.

So, in your component definition change the selector as follows:
selector: 'app-embedded-element'. In your main.ts file you will use the tag name you originally assigned (my-embedded-element).

I have changed it, but the same error is still showing in the browser's console. Also, it's already there when I tried to follow your readme from the previous suggestion

If it helps, I have uploaded my not working code, that is based on your readme, into GitHub: https://github.com/Banana828/AngularElements

I looked at your repo and I don't see the @angular/elements package in your package.json file. Did you run npm install @angular/elements ?

I tried your suggestion, but I got errors while installing. Seemed I used outdated packages. So it took me like 30 minutes to update all. But that seemed to be the trick. I thought I had installed elements globally...

Instead of bootstrapping your application consider using createApplication function instead. Your code in main.ts file will look like this:
    createApplication().then((ref) => {
        const injector = ref.injector;
        const myElement = createCustomElement(MyEmbeddedComponent, { injector });
        customElements.define('my-embedded-element', myElement);});


Okay, changed the code, rebuilt the whole thing, added it to the correct directory, and changed the index.html to get the new main-something.js... It's the same error still.

@Banana828 can I see the full angular.json file?

@Yuloa Galiulina Of course! I have added it to the original post.

Remove the polyfills property in the build section of your angular.json file. You are already providing the polyfills in main.ts

When I do that, the polyfills.js is not generated anymore. The main-something.js stays the same (no change). That suppose to happen?

That’s totally normal, because you imported your polyfills in the main.ts file. In fact it is recommended to generate a single file bundle for custom components, so that you can paste a single script containing all the necessary code

@Banana828 if there's no luck could you please follow the steps from a readme I created. You can skip the zoneless setup (which means you will need to provide zone.js in main.ts as you are already doing, plus no need to use provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection()).

I have downloaded your code and that seems to be working. Then I followed your tutorial to the letter. I had some trouble with the zone.js removal, but figured it out. Then I copied the main.js to my website and guess what? .... Still the same error with the injector. This is getting so frustrating!

Just letting you know, that I've updated my tutorial - readme. In the previous version I didn't take into account that angular introduced a new build system which essentially can produce a single production script, hence the overhead with a third party lib in the old tutorial. Now handling the production script became even easier! If anyone is going to follow my guide, I'd like to get some feedback to ensure it works for them too!

Sorry for the late reply... something came up. I have looked at it and it looks pretty good! More clear on the steps. It's easy to understand too. I didn't see anything with versions, which was my problem. Maybe add that?

Wow, thanks for taking a look! I wrote a Medium article based on that readme, hopefully it's even more understandable and easy to follow

Looks very good to me! I have bookmarked it. If you are looking for a new article to write idea: Libraries in Angular. Not much (good) info about those either. I'm trying to get a library working with a HttpClient injection, but that doesn't work.

make sure of angular dependencies and modify main.ts to import zone.js and check build configurations

As you can see in the code I shared, the zone.js is imported in the main.ts. But what do you mean by angular dependencies? Could you give a bit more context, please? Thanks

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
